# Parsing XML in C# using XmlDocument getting wrong Attribute values

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, xmldocument

I am trying to parse `XML file` in `c#`.

This is part of my code:

```
foreach (XmlNode node in dataNodes) 
{

        if (node.SelectSingleNode(@".//Imetnik").Attributes["matSub"] != null)
        {
            maticna = node.SelectSingleNode(@".//Imetnik").Attributes["matSub"].Value;
        }

        if (node.SelectSingleNode(@".//Imetnik").Attributes["davcna"] != null)
        {
            davcna = node.SelectSingleNode(@".//Imetnik").Attributes["davcna"].Value;
        }

        if (node.Attributes["iban"] != null && node.Attributes["rn"] != null)
        {
            iban = node.Attributes["iban"].Value;
            trr = node.Attributes["rn"].Value.Insert(5, "-");
        }
        
        if (node.Attributes["sSpre"] != null)
        {
            sifra_spremembe = node.Attributes["sSpre"].Value;
        }

        if (node.Attributes["dSpre"] != null)
        {
            datum_od = node.Attributes["dSpre"].Value;
        }

        if (node.Attributes["dOdprt"] != null)
        {
            datum_odprtja_racuna = node.Attributes["dOdprt"].Value;
        }

        if (node.Attributes["dZaprt"] != null)
        {
            datum_zaprtja_racuna = node.Attributes["dZaprt"].Value;
        }

//.... inserting values into database table ....
}
```

Problem that i am having is with `attributes`.
I have noticed that if i am in lets say `1st node` and `attribute` `dZaprt` does not exist in that node i will get value
from the `next node` that will have said attribute.

Xml node structure is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<RtrPod>
    --WITHOUT "dZaprt" attribute 
    <Tr rn="99999999" vr="T" sSpre="S" reg="P" dSpre="2022-06-17" dOdprt="2017-06-23" iban="5555" vir="B" maticnaPps="999999999">
        <PopolnoImeRacuna>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</PopolnoImeRacuna>
        <KratkoImeRacuna>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</KratkoImeRacuna>
        <Imetnik davcna="11111111" matSub="11111111" drz="111" ak="A" reg="P" vrsta="I">
            <PopolnoIme>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</PopolnoIme>
            <KratkoIme>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</KratkoIme>
            <Naslov sifTipNaslova="33" sifDrzava="333" sifObcina="333" sifPosta="33333" sifUlica="3333" sifNaselje="3333" stHisna="333" dodatek="C" sifHsmid="3333333">
                <Drzava>XXXXXXXX</Drzava>
                <Obcina>XXXXXXXX</Obcina>
                <Posta>XXXXXXXX</Posta>
                <Ulica>XXXXXXXX</Ulica>
                <Naselje>XXXXXXXX</Naselje>
            </Naslov>
        </Imetnik>
    </Tr>
    --with "dZaprt" attribute
        <Tr rn="555555555" vr="T" sSpre="Z" reg="P" dSpre="2022-06-17" dOdprt="2002-06-30" dZaprt="2022-06-17" iban="5555" vir="B" maticnaPps="5555555">
        <Imetnik matSub="555555" drz="555" ak="N" reg="P" vrsta="I">
            <PopolnoIme>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</PopolnoIme>
            <KratkoIme>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</KratkoIme>
            <Naslov sifTipNaslova="444" sifPosta="44444">
                <Posta>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</Posta>
            </Naslov>
        </Imetnik>
    </Tr>
</RtrPod>
```

Edit:

I have solved the issue by takeing advice from comments to rewrite whole thing using Linq.

Comment: That's not how you walk an XML document. Your code is actively searching for the next matching pattern, not trying to read the attributes of the current node. It's also executing the same search at least twice for every node, once to check if it's null and once again to get the same node it found earlier and get its value. With such a regular schema you could create a strongly typed class and deserialize the entire document into a `List<Whatever>`

Comment: What is `datum_zaprtja_racuna` and how is it used? The code you posted will iterate the entire document, storing attribute values in the same location but not using them. When that loop exits, the field/variable will contain only the last value encountered

Comment: After each loop i am inserting values into database table.

Comment: You can load an XML document directly into a dataset with [DataSet.ReadXxml](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataset.readxml?view=net-6.0) and store the datatables into the database. If you use SQL Server, you can use SqlBulkCopy to bulk import them using minimal logging with [SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServerAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.writetoserverasync?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: If you really want to access individual XML elements, it's a *LOT* easier to use LINQ-to-XML, parse the document into an XDocument and use LINQ queries to identify the elements you want, then process them. That still loads the entire document in memory though, the same way XML deserialization, DataSet or the legacy XmlDocument do. If you have a lot of data (100s of MBs) you can use [XmlReader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlreader?view=net-6.0) to read the document node by node

Comment: Right now it seems you're processing an already loaded document as if you were using a SAX parser or XmlReader. You get all the delays and complexity and none of the benefits. Instead of trying to deal with every single element in a loop, extract the code that generates a new object in a separate function meant to only work with an `Imetnik` element. Do the same for any lower-level objects. Instead of searching for nodes in the entire tree, just access the nodes in the *current* element.

Comment: I'd advise you to dump *all* of your XML documents into a Table Valued Parameter (or a temp table using SqlBulkCopy) and then use XQuery in SQL to parse it in bulk.

Comment: BTW Visual Studio tooling and the `svcutil` or `xsd` tools generate such classes methods from an XML's schema. You can use those classes with [XmlSerializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-deserialize-an-object) to deserialize the XML document into objects directly

Comment: @Charlieface that's no better than the current problem, just moved to another system, which is little better at actually parsing XML. If the data is small enough to be transferred to the database as XML, it's small enough to be deserialized in a single `XmlSerializer.Deserialize` call

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Not sure about that: performance might be better by doing it in batch, and there doesn't look to be anything being done here that SQL Server couldn't handle in XQuery. It sounds like OP has many XML files, so makes sense to do the whole lot in bulk.

Comment: Which is exactly why there's no reason to use SQL Server and XQuery. If the OP doesn't know how to write a correct XPath to retrieve a single attribute, how will they write a correct XPath in XQuery, a language few people remember in 2022? The reason the OP's code is so convoluted is that XML went out of fashion, the good docs and tutorials from the 2000s were removed, and the latest MS docs don't explain the basics any  more, they just reference the API for advanced users

Comment: I have solved the problem like some of you suggested by rewriting it to use Linq.